# Unable access Openbravo respository Forbidden error

Tags: java, openbravo

When I check out the openbravo repository according to the following [link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/81780319/Openbravo-Eclipse-Devel-Setup#scribd).

I got the 403 forbidden error. I think it needs credential. I would like to know any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions are out of date.  Openbravo is now on version 3 and is using Mercurial for source control instead of Subversion.

The current setup instructions can be found on the Openbravo wiki http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_setup_Eclipse_IDE

Comment: yes I did. When I check out from the link, it took many hours and not finished. Is that usual?

Comment: It is a very large repo - >1Gb on disk and many thousands of files.  If your connection is slow you may have trouble cloning the repo.

Comment: Is there any link to download the ready made openbravo source code project without using mercurial? Could u pls share me?